# What does differentiability imply in this proof?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

Hello I am reading a paper by Chua on Memristors. Working through it very slowly. It is series of math proofs relating to memristors. R Stanley Williams of HP labs says it is the mathematical framework behind memristors. I believe this question is appropriate for the math stack.

a [link](http://www.cpmt.org/scv/meetings/chua.pdf) to the paper in question. It is page 5 of the pdf.

[image]

If we let the R be a memristor characterized by a differentiable charge controlled $\phi-q$ curve, whose derivative is $M(q(t))$ and is known as the memristance of R then Chua is making the biconditonal statement

$$ \text{R is passive} \leftrightarrow M(q(t)) \geq 0$$

or more concisely

$$ p \leftrightarrow q$$

Now for an electronic element E

$$ \text {E is active} \leftrightarrow \text{The power p(t) of E} < 0 \wedge \text{the resistance r of E is less than zero}$$

$$ \text {E is passive} \leftrightarrow \text{The power p(t) of E} > 0 \wedge \text{the resistance r of E is greater than zero}$$

So we need to show two things

$$ q \rightarrow p $$

i.e. if $M(q(t)) \geq 0 \text { then R is passive}$

and

$$ p \rightarrow q $$

i.e. if $\text {R is passive then } M(q(t)) \geq 0$

The proof of $ q \rightarrow p$ is rather straight forward for me.

We assume $M(q(t)) is \geq 0$ therefore by the definition of power for a memristor $p(t) \geq 0$ so R is passive.

Proof of $ p \rightarrow q$ is giving me trouble. I believe its from learning calculus in a more application sense rather than the way a mathematician would. I recognize that Chua is proving the contrapostive to prove the claim

i.e. he is showing that $ \sim q \rightarrow \sim p$ which is equivalent to $p \rightarrow q$

As he is assuming $M(q(t)) < 0$ What I am not following is what he is getting at from the differentiability of the $\phi-q$ curve. I am not sure what differentaibility implies and am having difficulty figuring out what it does imply.

edit: I should mention this in terms of memristors, the memristance M(q(t)) is defined as

2nd Edit: My specific issue is sentence 3 of paragraph 2.

$$ M(q(t)) = \frac{d\phi(q(t))}{dq(t))}$$

i.e. M(q(t)) is the slope of the $\phi-q$ curve.